# Is it possible to embedded a Unity3D game play window in my Windows GUI app just like Unity3D editor?

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to embedded a Unity3D game play window (as screenshot shown below) in my Windows GUI app just like Unity3D editor? How to do it?

I'm trying to implement a windows application with following features:

1. In editing mode, user can drag a list of objects (aircraft, ship, radar...) in to a scene of a real world map. After dropping the object, it should be shown in the scene at the right place. Then user can drag and move it in the scene again. (similar with Unity3D Editor)
2. In editing mode, user can choose a navigation algorithm for each object.
3. In running mode, the object will be driving to move according to chosen navigation algorithm.

Since the GUI could be complicated (eg. TreeList/Table/MenuBar/...), I'd like to use a native windows GUI framework (wpf/winform/mfd/...) to do the GUI work.

I have found some answers related, but all of them are trying to embedded a Unity3d exe as a separated process.

[image]

Comment: I appreciated that you are used to wpf, but unity ui system isn't that bad, after the initial steepness of the rect transform and getting hang of layouts, its possible to build quite complex interfaces